# how change the subscription renewal in woocommerce when the user want it?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know how change the subscription renewal in woocommerce when the user want it. For example:

Before the end of the month(for example three days before), that the user can click on a button to renew their subscription if he wants it this way.

My development is:
1) The user can click on a button to renew.
2) Maintain automatic woocommerce renewal cycle.

The point two is perfectly configured in the system, but for point one, I don't know which hook to use.

Can you guide me a little bit? Please.

Thank you in advance.
Regards.

Comment: take a look at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/renewal-process/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw the link you put up. I don't understand one thing, there is to have a manual or automatic subscription, right? But not the two together?. I need to keep the automatic subscriptions but I want to give the user the option to renew the subscription.